# How to set a Directory as an Argument in Bash

Tags: bash, variables, ubuntu, directory

I am having trouble finding out how to set a directory as an argument in bash.

The directory I am trying to have as an argument is `/home/rrodriguez/Documents/one.`

Anywhere I try to look for an answer I see examples like dir = $1 but I cant seem to find an explanation of what this means or how to set it up so that it references my specific file location. Could anyone show me how to set up my variable for my path directory?

Adding my code for a better understanding of what im trying to do:

```
#!bin/bash

$1 == 'home/rrodriguez/Documents/one/'

dir = $1

touch -c $dir/*
ls -la $dir
wc$dir/*
```

Comment: What do you mean *as an argument in bash*? Do you mean you're writing a `bash` shell script and you want it as an argument to that? If it's a script, then when you call your script, by default, `$1`, `$2`, etc are the arguments passed to the script (if they exist). Just Google "bash script command line arguments" or something similar and you'll find lots of information on it.

Comment: ah thank you, it helped a little understand what the $1 means. So does that mean I have to set it to $1 == "path/to/directory/" ?

Comment: By the way: _"I see examples like `dir = $1`"_  No, you haven't.  No working bash example has spaces around the equal sign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider:

```
#!bin/bash

dir=$1
touch -c "$dir"/*
ls -la "$dir"
```

This script takes one argument, a directory name, and touches files in that directory and then displays a directory listing.  You can run it via:

```
bash script.sh 'home/rrodriguez/Documents/one/'
```

Since `home/rrodriguez/Documents/one/` is the first argument to the script, it is assigned to `$1` in the script.

#### Notes

In shell, never put spaces on either side of the `=` in an assignment.

I omitted the line `wc$dir/*` because it wasn't clear to me what the purpose of it was.

I put double-quotes around `$dir` to prevent the shell from, among other things, performing word-splitting.  This would matter if `dir` contains spaces.

Comment: Ohhhhhh thank you so very much, the $1 just looks for the first argument on the outside when running the script! Thank you so much! The `wc $dir/*` was just for the word count in my program

Comment: Yes, and `"$2"` is the second argument and `"$@"` is all the arguments.

Comment: Careful with just saying "$@" is all the arguments, there's a litte more to that bit than that; although I'd hope at least the very good bash man page had already been thoroughly read which clearly explains all this, and the $1, $2, $@, $*, ...?